# Passing non variable specific pointers in TwinCAT

Tags: twincat

I want to make a custom function block that uses FB_XmlSrvRead and FB_XmlSrvWrite from the Tc2_TcXmlDataSrv, but still does not specify the variable type being read/written, i.e. pass in a pointer DWORD which may point to any variable type for pSymAddr.

It is possible to placate the errors on compile using TO_DWORD(ADR()), but subsequently passing this DWORD into FB_XmlSrvRead/Write I seem to always get the 1808 error (ADSERR_DEVICE_SYMBOLNOTFOUND)

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a matter of you not assigning the ADR correctly? Should just be ADR(target) output as a PVOID which can be passed through as many layers as required.

Comment: Can you add some example code? It took me some time to understand your question. Partially because I never heard of the word "placate".

Answer (score 3):

What I was missing was the PVOID variable type, and trying to pass in the address as a DWORD. Thanks Steve! The docs are a little unhelpful in this regard  as the pSymAddr input is defined as DWORD not PVOID. Technically correct I believe, but not super helpful. When writing my encapsulating FB all that is required is to define the input as PVOID and everything works.